# StackOverflowError in spring oauth2 with custom ClientDetailsService

Tags: stack-overflow, spring-security-oauth2

I made my own implementation of ClientDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class JpaClientDetailsService implements ClientDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepositoy;

    @Override
    public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String clientId) throws ClientRegistrationException {
        ClientDetails client = clientRepositoy.findOne(clientId);
        if (client == null) {
            throw new ClientRegistrationException(String.format("Client with id %s not found", clientId));
        }
        return client;
    }
}
```

ClientRepository is a standard JpaRepository.

I configured an AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
    }
}
```

But when I go to `http://localhost:9999/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=lipton`, I get a

`java.lang.StackOverflowError: null. Spring loops on com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.loadClientByClientId(Unknown Source).`

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do not understand why, but if I inject my bean directly instead of injecting the interface, it works :

```
public class OAuth2ServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
...
  @Autowired
  private JpaClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;
...
```

it also works if I annotate my service with @Primary annotation:

```
@Service
@Primary
public class JpaClientDetailsService implements ClientDetailsService {
```

Comment: I had the same issue and after adding `@Primary` it works. The only reason I can see here is that the Spring context already have a `ClientDetailsService` bean and was not able to choose the correct bean

Answer (score 6):

I had similar problem. Finally I resolved bug when I gave my clientDetailsService another name i.e. myClientDetailsService and then injected this by name in AuthorizationServerConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "myClientDetailsService")
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;
...
```

I think that if my own implementation of ClientDetailsService wasn't yet created Spring inject into AuthorizationServerConfig some kind of proxy.

So, if you want to resolve this kind of bug you must be sure that
    Spring inject proper ClientDetailsService in
    AuthorizationServerConfig. You can achieve this if you:

1. give spring information about preference of your own ClientDetailsService (Arnaud answer), or
2. inject this service by name

Comment: Worked for me as well, I can't believe the error is not better handled by spring, so vauge...

Answer (score 2):

What ended up working for me was adding the ClientDetailsService @Bean to the @EnableAuthorizationServer class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration implements AuthorizationServerConfigurer {
    ...
    @Autowired
    ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;
    ...
    @Bean
    public ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService() {
        return new CustomClientDetailsServiceImpl();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the best solution is to be explicit - if you are autowiring a clientDetailsService - then say so.

```
@Autowired
ClientDetailsService myClientDetailsService;

@Override
public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        endpoints.setClientDetailsService(myClientDetailsService);
       ....
}
```

However, My problem was slightly different and the above solutions did not work.  Here are the conditions that created it.
I created a CustomTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter - which required an instance of OAuth2RequestFactory. 
I created my instance of OAuth2RequestFactory with a call to   endpoints.getOAuth2RequestFactory(); before the clientDetailsService had been set.

If The OAuth2RequestFactory gets created this way, DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory gets created with a default clientDetailsService, so even if you set the clientDetailsService later explicitly in the AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer it will not be in the OAuth2RequestFactory used by your custom Filter.

So in sum in this edge case

```
public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
     oAuth2RequestFactory = endpoints.getOAuth2RequestFactory();
     endpoints.setClientDetailsService(myClientDetailsService);
    ...
    }
```

wont work but

```
public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
endpoints.setClientDetailsService(myClientDetailsService);
 oAuth2RequestFactory = endpoints.getOAuth2RequestFactory();
...
}
```

will.

Another way to be sure is to create your own OAuth2RequestFatory

```
  oauth2RequestFactory = new DefaultTokenRequestFactory(myClientDetailsService);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this annotating @Primary in my costum ClientDetailsService:

```
@Service
@Primary
public class ClientDetailsServiceImp implements ClientDetailsService {
```